# How to deal with a Java object that might or might not be an array, and might or might not be an array of primitives

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I'm writing some code that works with the JMX api. Specifically I am making use of the `getAttribute` method of `MBeanServerConnection`

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#getAttribute%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20java.lang.String%29) for the `getAttribute` method says that it returns `Object`, but what I have found is that depending on the MBean, sometimes it can return an `Object`, and other times it can return an `Object[]` array.

Because I want to deal with the return from `getAttribute` consistently, I have written the following code:

```
Object attr = mBeanServer.getAttribute(objName, attributeName);
Object[] attributes = new Object[]{};

if (attr.getClass().isArray()) {
    attributes = (Object[])attr; // create my array by casting the return from getAttribute
} else {
    attributes = new Object[] {attr}; // create my array with just one element
}

for (int i=0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    // deal with each attribute ...
}
```

Hopefully you can see the idea. It's probably a naive solution, but basically I want to deal with the return from `getAttribute` consistently, regardless of whether its a single `Object` or an `Object[]` array.

The above works ... for the most part! ... but I've now found a case where 'getAttribute' has returned an array of `long` (the primitive, rather than class). Because of this, my cast throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

I understand the exception - it cannot cast an array of `long` to an array of `Object` - but I don't know how to solve it.

Personally, I think the method signature of `getAttribute` sucks! Returning 'Object' to cover pretty much anything - an object, an array of objects, or an array of primitives - feels like a cop out to me. But its not my api, and I've got to work with it.

Appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how I can solve this?

Cheers

Nathan

Comment: If you do get an array of longs (or any other primitive), do you wish to handle it, or will you just reject/ignore it?  And if you do handle it, would using the wrapper class (Long, Integer, etc.) suffice or would you work with the values in their primitive state?

Comment: I need to handle primitives, so I've taken your solution below and used it to convert the array of primitives into an array of the relevant wrapper. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTest
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    evaluate("Hello");
    evaluate(new Boolean[]{Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE});
    evaluate(new int[]{0, 1, 2});
    evaluate(null);
  }

  public static void evaluate(Object object)
  {
    List<String> primitiveArrayTypes = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
        "boolean[]", "byte[]", "char[]", "double[]",
        "float[]", "int[]", "long[]", "short[]"
    });

    if (object == null)
    {
      System.out.println("Null object.");
      return;
    }

    Class objClass = object.getClass();

    if (objClass.isArray())
    {
      if (primitiveArrayTypes.contains(objClass.getCanonicalName()))
      {
        System.out.println("Contents of primitive array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object); i++)
        {
          System.out.println(Array.get(object, i));
        }
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Contents of Object array:");
        for (Object obj : (Object[]) object)  // cast should now always work
        {
          System.out.println(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Not an array: " + object);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (o instanceof int[]) {
   ...
}
else if (o instanceof boolean[]) {
   ...
}
...
```

Maybe there's some more elegant solution, but you don't tell what you want to do with the attribute.